# How to verify login permissions using a DataSet and QueryBuilder?

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, authentication

I wasnt quite sure how to properly write the question so bear with me please, here i'll explain as much as I can. And sorry if its too long.
I am building a basic school project that allows employees to register their time-in and time-out of the job to an Access Database, but I am currently struggling with the Login Form.
After many attempts I decided to go the easy way and use both the DataSet designer and the Query Builder from Visual Studio.

This is what I have right now:

An "EmpleadosDataSet" with a "_tblUser" DataTable and its TableAdapter, this adapter uses a query which I've named "GetDataLogin". Heres an image for reference [EmpleadosDataSet Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDgEN.png)

What the query does is fill the "_tblUserDataTable" like this:

```
SELECT [ID EMPLEADO], USUARIO, CONTRASEÑA, PERMISOS
FROM [_tblUser]
WHERE (USUARIO = ?) AND (CONTRASEÑA = ?)
```

(Notice how I'm not using the PERMISOS at all after selecting it because that´s what I need help with)

For this to work on my code I instantiate my _tblUserDataTable from the EmpleadosDataSet and its TableAdapter:

```
Private dtLogin As New EmpleadosDataSet._tblUserDataTable
Private taLogin As New EmpleadosDataSetTableAdapters._tblUserTableAdapter
```

Then I pass both onto a button click event with this:

```
Private Sub _Button2_Acceder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _Button2_Acceder.Click

    dtLogin = taLogin.GetDataLogin(_TxtUsuario.Text, _TxtContrasena.Text)
    If dtLogin.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Bienvenido")
    Else
            MsgBox("No esta registrado")
    End If
End Sub
```

This works just fine, however, I want to open a different form depending on whether the employee is an "user" or an "admin". This information is stored in the same dataset on a column named "PERMISOS", but I have no clue how to make the query that selects the value from said column and verify it.
My best bet is that I´ll have the query do SELECT PERMISOS and somehow assign that value to a variable that I can then verify with an If statement?
Something with this structure (this is just an example of what I need but I do not know if its the correct procedure, also, *value from PERMISOS column* is not a variable name or anything, im putting it for reference of what i need to be there):

```
If **value from PERMISOS column** = "admin" Then
Me.Hide()
Form2_admin.Show()
ElseIf **value from PERMISOS column** = "user" Then
Me.Hide()
Form3_user.Show()
```

I am not sure if that would be correct at all, bear with me, I havent been able to find how to even do that, assign the value of the column that I already selected with the query to a variable. Every info about this that I find is from people who rather code the whole database connection and queries themselves, haven´t found anything using the designer and query builder that refers to user permissions.
So that's basically what I need help with, how to either use a query or something else to verify user permissions like that, in other words, how to get the *-value from PERMISOS column-*

And just if clarification is needed, I did also use the Data Source wizard to connect to the Access Database, as it was the easier way, my DataSets are connected to that and filled with the info from it

PS: I understand some of my methods are incorrect, such as storing passwords as plain text, but please understand this is a simple practice about WindowsForms in general, not trying to learn security or others as of right now, will eventually do but right now I just need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can learn to write some basic ADO.net code, you will be able to get the data you want in the format your want.

First the user interface code. You pass the values in the 2 text boxes to a function and get back the data you want. Notice that the user interface doesn't know or care where the data is coming from. It is completely disconnected from the database.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
    Dim permission = ValidateEmployee(_TxtUsuario.Text, _TxtContrasena.Text)
    If permission = "admin" Then
        Me.Hide()
        Form2_admin.Show()
    ElseIf permission = "user" Then
        Me.Hide()
        Form3_user.Show()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No esta registrado")
    End If
End Sub
```

The data access code is all in the function and this function doesn't know anything about the user interface. It has not idea that the parameters are coming from text boxes. If you switched this to a web app, you could still use this function; just change where the parameters values are coming from.

The Using blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

We can use named parameters with Access but Access pays no attention to the name. For Access (OleDb) these are positional parameters which means that the order that they appear in the sql query must match the order that they are added to the parameters collection (`cmd.Parameters.Add`)

```vb
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Function ValidateEmployee(user As String, pword As String) As String
    Dim permissions As String
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select PERMISOS 
                                        From _tblUser 
                                        Where USUARIO = @User 
                                        AND CONTRASEÑA = @Password;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = user
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = pword
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If reader.HasRows Then
                reader.Read()
                permissions = reader("PERMISOS").ToString
            Else
                permissions = ""
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
    Return permissions
End Function
```

The only big problem left is storing passwords as plain text. They should be salted and encrypted to be safe but that is an issue for another day.

Comment: Just one thing however, I notice the function requires a Connection string "explicitly" written. Since, as stated, I used the Data Source wizard from Visual Studio which handles this by itself and doesnt explicitly show the connection string code inside the form (I understand it exists, it just isn't inside the form's code). So just to be sure, does the connection string still have to explicitly be there? I feel is kind of redundant as the connection is already made, but maybe i am being ignorant and the string the wizard makes is different to this one. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @JesúsSantoyo They are not too difficult. `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\the path to your database;` If that Wizard created some objects that you use check the properties in design view. Also probably buried in the files that the wizard created.

Comment: I might be missing something else, but no matter how I put the connection string (Ive used the one made by the wizard, i've used one set by myself) I'm still getting an exception at `Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader` that says "ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized"

Comment: Forgot to put cn, the second parameter of the command constructor. I will edit my answer. `AND CONTRASEÑA = @Password;)", cn)`

Comment: Getting a new exception on same line, this one says "Characters found after the end of the SQL statement.", upon doing some research it appears to be that Access cannot do this

Comment: So sorry! I had an extra closing parenthesis that doesn't belong inside the quotation marks. Should be `AND CONTRASEÑA = @Password;", cn)`

Comment: Worry not! Had I not been such a newbie I would have figured it out, so thank you for the correction. Finally got it to work, thank you so much